# Hangfire : The method UseSqlServerStorage is missing

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, hangfire

I'm trying to install HangFire for a ASP.NET Code Project.

When I follow then official doc (https://www.hangfire.io/blog/2016/07/16/hangfire-1.6.0.html) or other link ressources (http://www.dotnetjalps.com/2017/04/aspnet-core-hangfire-integation.html), it's sounds clear. Add this

```
services.AddHangfire(config=>config.UseSqlServerStorage(Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyConnectionString")));
```

But it doesn't work. This extension method doesn't exist. Am I miss something ?

Comment: Install-Package Hangfire.SqlServer

Comment: I did it, but it still doesn't work. Moreover, in those links, it's writted that the package is not needed.

Comment: Hangfire.SqlServer is a dependency, so it should have installed automatically. Have a look in your Nuget Dependencies and expand the Hangfire section - you should see all three hangfire dependencies listed (AspNetCore, Core, SqlServer) - if not, then try removing and reinstalling.

Comment: This may not be helpful, but I do vaguely remember having a similar issue when I installed Hangfire on a core project - which IIRC ended up being due to a naming conflict with the Hangfire GlobalConfiguration object and another library I had installed.

Comment: The Hangfire package contains Hangfire.SqlServer. What is IIRC ?

Comment: OKay so it's weird. I close my solution, delete temp file and packages and re-add and it's working !

Comment: IIRC = If I recall correctly :)
Glad you sorted it out

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, I found the answser ..

I had to delete HangFire package, close my Visual Studio 2017 solution and clean the obj and bin folder.

Then, I reopen it, add HangFire.AspNetCore and HangFire.SQLServer packages. Then it works.

Answer (score 7):

You might be missing the HangFire.SqlServer package. Once I added that to my project it worked.
You can find the most recent version of the package here.

```
https://www.nuget.org/packages/HangFire.SqlServer/
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue and it was caused because I already had *GlobalConfiguration* in my Startup and it was referencing *System.Web.Http.GlobalConfiguration*. Now I thought Hangfire would add this *UseSqlServerStorage()* as an extension method, like Swagger does for example, but instead Hangfire brings its own version of this file.

Referencing it directly worked for me:

```
Hangfire.GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseSqlServerStorage("connection_string");
```